# How to calculate the time complexity of searching in an AVL tree?

Tags: avl-tree

I know that AVL tree search algorithm's time complexity is O(log n) but how it's derived?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Think about it this way. At every node in the tree, you essentially have three options:

1. You have found the search key and can end the search
2. Proceed to search in the left subtree (if any)
3. Proceed to search in the right subtree (if any)

At the end of each step, you essentially divide the problem into two halves and discard one of them. This means that at the end of each step, you are left with exactly half of the problem set that you had before the step.
This is similar to how binary search works.

And that explains the log n time complexity.